Possible implications of the bound $\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{m_{1}+m_{2}=n}\lambda\left(m_{1}\right)\lambda\left(m_{2}\right)=O\left(x\right)$
Let $\lambda(n)$ be the Liouville function and consider the Goldbach-type problem $\sum_{m_{1}+m_{2}=n}\lambda\left(m_{1}\right)\lambda\left(m_{2}\right)$. Assume the Riemann hypothesis, the semplicity of the non-trivial zeros and that the bound $$\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{m_{1}+m_{2}=n}\lambda\left(m_{1}\right)\lambda\left(m_{2}\right)=O\left(x\right)$$ holds as $x\rightarrow \infty$. I was wondering if such a result had any interesting implications, perhaps (but not necessarily) to a "Chowla-type function" $\sum_{n\leq x}\lambda\left(n\right)\lambda\left(n+h\right)\, h \geq 2$, or it is just a curiosity. The idea starts from the fact that it is well known that Goldbach's conjecture and the twin prime problem are connected, so I wondered whether such a result had a similar connection.

It is unlikely that the stated bound holds. The double sum is over the pairs $(m_1,m_2)$ satisfying $m_1+m_2\leq x$. If we change the condition to $m_1,m_2\leq x$, then the $O(x)$ bound provably fails.

@GHfromMO I tried some numerical simulations and it seems that the bound might make sense

You cannot detect the difference between $x$ and $x\log\log x$ with numberical simulations (since you cannot sum up to $x=10^{100000}$). Compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture

@GHfromMO actually I don’t think the known negative results on Mertens conjecture are enough to refute either claim unconditionally, though it should be possible to rule out both assuming linear independence of the zeroes of zeta.

@TerryTao You are right. Originally I had Littlewood's result in mind concerning $\psi(x)-x$, not realizing that the corresponding estimates for the summatory function of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are not available yet. Even though I looked at the Wikipedia page. Oh well. There is a heatwave here, the temperature is constant 33 C (= 91 F) in my apartment (even during the night with open windows).

@GHfromMO Maybe I'm missing something but, if I understand correctly, your skepticism derives from the fact that, by posing the problem in terms of explicit formulas, there could be a contribution deriving from the series on zeros, so, as in the case of the Mertens function , one has estimates of the type $O(x^{1/2+\varepsilon}$) (under RH). However, when one considers an average of a convolution, one obtains a "regularizing" effect, with some series on zeros that become absolutely convergent (an example is the Goldbach problem). Maybe I didn't quite understand your objection.

@TerryTao Just to clarify, do you think that by assuming the linear independence of the zeros of the zeta, the estimate I proposed can be excluded? If I interpreted your comment correctly, I don't understand how you arrived at that idea

@Yep We expect that $\sum_{m\leq x}\lambda(m)=O(\sqrt{x})$ is false, hence my skepticism. Note that $\sum_{m_1,m_2\leq x}\lambda(m_1)\lambda(m_2)$ is the square of the previous sum, while your sum is a variant of that, namely $\sum_{m_1+m_2\leq x}\lambda(m_1)\lambda(m_2)$.
